# iOS navigation history

Tags: ios4, uiviewcontroller

I have a `mapViewController`, `tagsViewController` and `detailViewController`. In my mapViewController `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method I want to know if `tagsViewController` or `detailViewController` was just removed so I can do some custom stuff.

So is there a way to know what view was just removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notifications look like a better approach here. Rather than you having to track the navigation controller. Let those two controllers tell you if they are going off. Although this would mean that you won't have that information in `viewWillAppear:` but you will have that information as soon as the views are unloaded.

Comment: So it's okay for controllers to know about each other?

Comment: There is a dependency. It is not like `detailViewController` is telling `mapViewController` to do something. We are posting a notification saying that `detailViewController` is no longer on as we are interested in getting that information elsewhere. And since `mapViewController` is interested, it listens to it and acts. There is a weak knowledge but that is something we want to keep track of.